# How to lint custom SASS functions?

Tags: javascript, sass

Say I have the following SASS...

```
@function myCustomFunction($param) {
    @return ($param);
}

h1 { font-size: myCustomFunctionWithATypo(32); }
```

This doesn't raise any linting errors as it is interpreting  `myCustomFunctionWithATypo` as a css3 function, even though it doesn't exist.

Is there anything I can use to lint the naming of a custom function so that this is caught?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gulp you can set your gulp task as the following

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'));
});
```

By setting in such a way code shows error on line2 and would not compile succesfully to css

Hope this helps